# JQuery selecting dynamically generated html without adding event (with live)

Tags: html, jquery

Several posts on stackoverflow say to use live to select dynamically generated html. However you need an event like click to use live. What do you do if you just want to use .val or .html and change the element instead of adding an event handler?

(Solution with live: [Jquery not working with dynamically created table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839859/jquery-not-working-with-dynamically-created-table))

I am generating code through:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/JobFeed/JobFeed.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html) {
            $("#jobFeed").html(html);
        }
    });
```

The html once generated looks like this (with the form repeated several times):

```
<div id="jobFeed" class="contentContainer">
     <div id="jobs">
         <div class="job">
             <form class="subscription">
             </form>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I then add inputs with:

```
 $("form .subscription").html("<input ... />");
```

Comment: Do you have a use-case you'd like to use as the basis for your question? What are you doing, what's going wrong, and what, specifically, do you want help with? Incidentally, for client-side questions to do with HTML/CSS/JS, please consider posting a demo to [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar. That way it reduces the work *we* have to do to help you, which is usually a good thing for those asking questions.

Comment: You will need to elaborate on your question, and possibly add some sample code. However, in general, you can just call `.val()`, `.html()`, etc. normally any time *after* the dynamically generated html has been added to the DOM. i.e.  you can't manipulate it until it exists

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but you can wrap any HTML string in `$(...)` and then you can call all the usual jquery methods on it as if it's already in the Dom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin called "livequery" and do something like this:

```
$(selector).livequery(function(){ 

});
```

As you can see, there is no `click` or other event that you must use.

**Plugin link**: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

**On github**: https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery

Hope this helps :-)