# Using .jquery .on() without an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have input elements that get appended to my HTML document that I need to get the value of. I understand that .on() should be used to get appended elements, but .on() expects an event to activate it, and I don't need an event.

Below is the code. #save_design is on a different part of the page. #fields_cnt is the parent that holds all my appended forms. .reg_field is the element I'm trying to get the value of. The first child works because that form is present when the document is loaded, or in other words, it is not appended. The other children all returns values undefined, or false depending on the input type and the logic I'm applying to it. This leads me to believe that .on() or something close to it should be used.

**To clarify, I am trying to get the value of an appended input when #save_design is clicked.**

```
$('#save_design').click( function() {
        group_text[form_count] = $('#fields_cnt .field_group:nth-child(' + child + ') .reg_field').val();
```

I have tried replacing the originating click event as so. It has not worked.

```
$('body').on('click', '#save_design', function(){
```

I have tried using .on() without an event or event object. It has also not worked.

```
        $('body').on('', '', function(){ 
            group_text[form_count] = $('#fields_cnt .field_group:nth-child(' + child + ') .reg_field').val(); 
        });
```

I have found a plugin that should work.

[JQuery selecting dynamically generated html without adding event (with live)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144846/jquery-selecting-dynamically-generated-html-without-adding-event-with-live)

This is not ideal, because as stated in the github readme, it is being rewritten. Also, the SO answer is 3 years old now, so it may no longer be the correct answer.

https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery

I'd like to find a more direct solution. Is there a way to do this natively in jQuery? Is there a way to use .on() without an event, and if so, what's the appropriate syntax?

**UPDATE:** *Clarification:* The input fields get appended when an add field button is pressed. Their values change after they are appended. I would prefer not to rerecord the value of an input, every time it is altered.

**UPDATE** Here is the HTML structure to give a better idea of how I'm defining child.

```
<div id="fields_cnt">
  <div id="field_group_1" class="field_group form-group">
      <input placeholder="Field" class="reg_field form-control" />
  </div>
  <!-- This is appended by jQuery. There may be multiple of these -->
  <div id="field_group_2" class="field_group form-group">
      <input placeholder="Field" class="reg_field form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73808/discussion-on-question-by-goose-using-jquery-on-without-an-event).

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, you can add it as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @j08691 I can not answer my question because it has been locked. If it is unlocked, I will answer my question thoroughly and mark it as accepted. Please help unlock it if you can. I think this may help someone in the future.

Comment: chat is blocked by my corporate network.  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a great solution to my problem. It takes a different approach on selecting the element, but ultimately works and results in drier code.

Here, I use each, to grab each instance of the appended element I am trying to select. This returns the desired value.

```
$('.reg_field').each( function() {
    group_text[form_count] = $(this).val();
    form_count++;
});
```

I suspect the issue was my previous selector was unable to use $(this), which seems to work in more cases for appended elements. Another possibility that was brought up in the comments was the use of nth-child in the middle of a selection. I am not sure on these points, and would appreciate a better explanation. Hopefully this will help for someone who faces the same issue. Also, I appreciate the help on getting me to focus on the selection rather than the binding.